# Vue relative path image dependecy not found

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-4

In my template I am using code

```
<img src="@/assets/images/logo-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
```

OR

```
<img src="./assets/images/logo-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
```

It gives the following error

```
This dependency was not found:

* @/assets/images/logo-icon.png in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js??ref--6!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/Header.vue?vue&type=template&id=61dd7a3d
```

Tried using url loader in vue.config.js still the same issue

> UPDATE: Solved

Simply using `<img src="/assets/images/logo-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />` instead of `<img src="assets/images/logo-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />`

Solved my problem,. and @ doesn't work with the latest Vue version I guess and it wasn't also in the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `require`?
For example:

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/images/logo-icon.png')" />
```

Comment: I have but it wasn't working. I got it working by simply using '/path-to-assets'. The . and @ does not works with the latest version I guess and it wasn't in the documentation also.

Comment: Okay! Also depends on your project settings.